# Is there a way to use strings on linked lists?

Tags: c

I have to use linked lists to organize strings from the user, but I keep having the same error message: 
"format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (**)."
I'm not really sure how to solve this and need some help.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct report {
    char *name;
    char *title;
    struct report *next;  } t_report;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    t_report *in_report;  
    t_report* next_report;  
    int answer;

    in_report = (t_report*)malloc(sizeof(t_report));    
    if (in_report == NULL)  {    
        exit (1);    
    }  
    next_report = in_report;  
    while (1)  {  
        printf("Digite autor da denuncia:\n");  
        scanf("%s", &next_report->name);  
        printf("Digite o titulo da denuncia:\n");  
        scanf("%s", &next_report->title);  
        printf("Deseja inserir uma nova denuncia? Digite <1>para SIM e <2> para NÃO\n");  
        scanf("%i", &answer);    
        if (answer == 1)  {
            next_report->next = (t_report*)malloc(sizeof(t_report));
            next_report = next_report->next;  
        }  else break;  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
    next_report->next = NULL;  
    next_report = in_report;  
    while (next_report != NULL)  {
        printf("name: %s, title: %s\n", next_report->name, next_report->title);
        next_report = next_report->next;  
    }  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the code readable. Don't put multiple statements on a single line, split it up into multiple lines. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I've changed from block quote to code block, but please indent your code properly and tidy it up.

Comment: I'm sorry, first time asking on stackoverflow. I made a few changes, can you please check?

Comment: The error message is quite straight forward. `scanf("%s", &next_report->title);` Here `title` already is a pointer to `char`. Taking the address creates invalid type. You must use `scanf("%s", next_report->title);` instead. But before you do this you must fix another error: You must allocate memory for the strings you try to read.

Comment: _"Is there a way to use strings on linked lists?"_ Yes there is a way.

Comment: The actual error from compiler will tell the line number where the error was detected. As Gerhardh mentioned `name` and `title` are already pointers you need not to reference them again.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are allocating memory for `struct` but not for `char *title`
For removing this error you have to choices.

1. Use below structure

   `typedef struct report
   {
       char name[20];
       char title[20];
       struct report *next; 
   }
   t_report;`
2. Explicitly allocate memory for `title` and `name`
   After allocating memory for `struct` i.e. `in_report = (t_report*)malloc(sizeof(t_report));` (or any other variables you have created)
   Allocate memory for string pointer as below

   `in_report->title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
   in_report->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);`

   In `scanf` not need to use `&` for reading `string`

   `scanf("%s", next_report->title);` it will work fine;

Comment: Now it compiles but when comes to the second alternative in the code which is add a new report, goes to a infinite loop of questions. I took your second sugestion because title must contain at least 3 words, so it can't be a char.

Comment: @Pedro what does this line look like in your updated code: `scanf("%i", &answer);` ? Did you remove the & here? This line should still have the &.

Comment: I didn't, only on scanf("%s", next_report->title)

Comment: Hey @Pedro look into [this code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/L2qoRXd4Ja)  specifically line No. 32 and 33 the only change